# Java spring hibernate webservice utf8 not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, web-services

As a title I have written a `webservice` using spring framework and hibernate. When I retrieve data from database (test in postman),  I receive a `?` instead of expected data.

code
web.xml

```
 <filter>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8;databaseName=dbName" />

    <beans:property name="username" value="username" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
</beans:bean>
```

main controller I have add

```
@Bean
public StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter() {
    return new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

any suggest for problem, please tell me, thank you for reading, sorry for my English

Comment: I using gson for webservice

Comment: Did you debug your code and see at what point it fails?

Comment: When I retrieve and show in jsp file, anything is oke, I think problem is when I convert to gson, Can you tell me how debug webservice test in postman in eclipse

Comment: I use new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create().toJson(usersDAO.getAllUsers());

Comment: Sorry I have never used gson but have used Jackson. Not sure how open are you to  change your application to use Jackson which is easier to use

Comment: Thank for suggest, can you tell me serialize name when use Jackson

Comment: Check out the tutorial. this will tell you each and every step in detail http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: were you able to figure it out ?

Comment: sorry for time of you, I forgot produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8" of header method ResponseBody : (